# print polygon from "the_geom" field in postGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a postGIS database with plots and features (owner, area, address, etc) and I would like to print any selection of that like a card. 
I mean I would like to show each record in a page with the bunch of datas and a draw of the polygon that represent the plot . Then I wonder if is possible to read "the geom" field of each record for drawing it.
If not, I would like to know the best method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use DB Manager tool (`Database > DB Manager > DB Manager`) to connect to your PostGIS database and then add manually the tables / views you want to QGIS map canvas. Before clicking DB Manager, you will need to specify connection details to your DB through `Layer > Add Layer > Add PostGIS layers...`

Answer (score 0):

Finnally I have found this way to do that....I don't  know if there are best solution. 
The idea is convert "the_geom" column to a ASCII string through "ST_AsText" function and convert the results in a list of points and then in a QPolygons. This is a snippet, there are a few more lines to fit the polygon to a area of the paper.

```
self.coordenadasGuardadas = False
self.xMin=0.00
self.xMax=0.00
self.yMin=0.00
self.yMax=0.00
self.stringquery = "SELECT ST_AsText(the_geom) FROM "mytable" WHERE "mycondition" #I select the "the_geom" column in a string with this format: POLYGON((p1x p1y, p2x p2y,...,pnx pny))

self.myquery.exec_(self.stringquery)
self.listaPuntosPoly = []               
while self.myquery.next():
    self.listaPuntos=self.myquery.value(0)
    self.listaPuntos = self.listaPuntos[9:-2]#I remove "POLYGON((" and "))" from the string and now I have "p1x p1y, p2x p2y,...,pnx pny"

    self.puntos = self.listaPuntos.split(",")
    if self.coordenadasGuardadas == False:
        self.punto0 = self.puntos[0].split()
        self.punto0X = float(self.punto0[0])
        self.punto0Y = -1.0*float(self.punto0[1])
        self.xMin=self.xMax=self.punto0X
        self.yMin=self.yMax=self.punto0Y
        self.coordenadasGuardadas = True
    for p in self.puntos:
        self.punto=p.split()
        self.puntoF= QtCore.QPointF(float(self.punto[0].strip(')(')), -1.0*float(self.punto[1].strip(')(')))
        if self.puntoF.x() < self.xMin:
            self.xMin = self.puntoF.x()
        if self.puntoF.x() > self.xMax:
            self.xMax = self.puntoF.x()
        if self.puntoF.y() < self.yMin:
            self.yMin = self.puntoF.y()
        if self.puntoF.y() > self.yMax:
            self.yMax = self.puntoF.y()
        self.listaPuntosPoly.append(self.puntoF)
    self.listaParcelasParaImprimir.append(self.listaPuntosPoly)

    self.printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
    self.dialogo = QtGui.QPrintDialog(self.printer)
    if self.dialogo.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        self.printer.newPage()
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 1)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.lightGray)
        mipainter = QtGui.QPainter(self.printer)
        mipainter.setPen(pen)
        mipainter.setBrush(brush)

        for self.parcela in self.listaParcelasParaImprimir:
            self.poli=QtGui.QPolygonF(self.parcela)
            mipainter.drawPolygon(self.poli)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make an "Atlas" in QGIS using your PostGIS data...